# Flutter - android: Exception when convert large file (more than 1GB) to byte

Tags: android, flutter, file, dart-io

I'm using **dart:io** to convert file to bytes. with image and short video it's work. but with large file (more than 1GB) i got error

```
E/flutter (16030): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: NewExternalTypedData expects argument 'length' to be in the range [0..1073741823].
```

my code

```
Uint8List bytes;
          try {
            bytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
            print('bytes $bytes');
            lengthInBytes = bytes.buffer.asByteData().lengthInBytes;
          } catch (e) {
            print('e $e');
          }
```

it's look like limit of memory. any way to solve this?

Comment: Why are you doing that? What is the use case you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i'm try to get lengthInBytes to upload from phone to my api. this is a one param

Comment: how are you uploading your data?

Comment: You are not converting a file to bytes. You are just trying to place the bytes of a file in memory. If you only want to know file size then that is a bad idea. The File class can simply tell you the size of the file.

Comment: I have uploaded the whole file

Comment: api is designing 2 steps to upload 1 file.
First call an api to upload the file size to create a link on s3. then push the file to that link

Comment: lengthInBytes is capacity when call first api

Answer (score 1):

Try uploading in chunks of the file size is bigger. You can try some package like
https://pub.dev/packages/chunked_uploader

```dart
ChunkedUploader chunkedUploader = ChunkedUploader(Dio(BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: 'https://example.com/api',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer'})));
try {
  Response? response = await chunkedUploader.upload(
      filePath: '/path/to/file',
      maxChunkSize: 500000,
      path: '/file',
      onUploadProgress: (progress) => print(progress));
  print(response);
} on DioError catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

It will automatically convert into chunks and upload

Comment: there is no no need to use any non standard package: ordinary `http` package and `MultipartFile`  is good enough

Comment: Only if the range is between 0..1073741823

Comment: what range? you mean the uploaded file size? where did you get that limit from?

Comment: In the error message mentioned by the op

Comment: the error says there is no enough memory to keep the whole file content, it does not come from the uploading process

Comment: Yeah so not sure if the file can be handled by all devices. Thats why chunked upload is better

Comment: with `MultipartFile` you call upload files that have even hundreds or thousands of GB - no  `chunked_uploader` is needed

Comment: Yes you are right but only if my device is capable of handling that big file I think. if my file is already 2 GB and I don't have 2gd Ram then does it still work?

Comment: yes, it will work

Comment: I have recently tried it and if my phone's ram doesn't have enough space to handle such a big file then it isn't working.. Will check and update here

Comment: so you used [MultipartRequest](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html) to upload your file? just like in the sample code snippet from the doc link?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution to get file size

```
imageFile.lengthSync()
```

it's solve my problem.  **readAsBytesSync** make full memory